# Tkinter ttk.Checkbox not functioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I encountered a bug. The `ttk.Checkbutton` in my codes has a constant value `0`. And when I click it, the value doesn't change at all. But the strange thing is, other `ttk.Checkbutton` works just fine. Here is the troublesome code:

```
c1=ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_y',variable=self.Int4,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
#c5 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_z',variable=self.Int5,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
```

`c1` works fine for me, but `c5` no, basically, they are the same code. Is someone have the same problem? I can't figure it out.

When I check the button:

[image]

The results comes like this:

[image]

A constant `0` outputs, but if I change to `c1` check button:

[image]

It works.

[image]

Codes are changed into:

```
c1 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='z轴',variable=self.Int1,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
c1.grid(row=3,column=0)
#c5 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='z轴',variable=self.Int5,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
#c5.grid(row=3,column=0)
```

Strange things.

Here is my whole work.

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from tkinter import *

def read_file(path):
    print(path)
    file = open(path,'rb')
    cuvA = []
    cuvB = []
    cuvC = []
    cuvD = []
    dic = {}
    dic['flag'] = False
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        words = line.split()
        if words != []:
            for i in range(1,5):
                if i == 1:
                    cuvA.append(int(words[i-1]))
                elif i == 2:
                    cuvB.append(int(words[i-1]))
                elif i == 3:
                    cuvC.append(int(words[i-1]))
                elif i == 4:
                    cuvD.append(int(words[i-1]))
        else:
            dic['x'] = range(0,len(cuvA))
            dic['cuvA'] = cuvA
            dic['cuvB'] = cuvB
            dic['cuvC'] = cuvC
            dic['cuvD'] = cuvD
            dic['flag'] = True
            print(cuvA)
            break
    return dic

class reader():
    def __init__(self,txt,container):
        data = txt.get()
        self.speed = 0
        self.dic = read_file(data)
        print(len(self.dic['x']))
        self.y = self.dic['cuvA']
        self.y2 = self.dic['cuvB']
        self.y3 = self.dic['cuvC']
        self.y4 = self.dic['cuvD']
        self.x = np.arange(0,100,1)
        self.Int1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Int2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Int3 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Int4 = tk.IntVar()
        self.Int5 = tk.IntVar()
        c1 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_z',variable=self.Int1,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
        c2 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='standard_axis',variable=self.Int2,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check2)
        c3 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_x',variable=self.Int3,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check3)
        c4 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_y',variable=self.Int4,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check4)
        #c5 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_z',variable=self.Int5,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
        c3.grid(row=3,column=2)
        c2.grid(row=3,column=1)
        c1.grid(row=3,column=0)
        c4.grid(row=3,column=3)
        #c5.grid(row=3,column=0)

        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(4,4),dpi=100)
        p = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure,container)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4,columnspan=4,sticky='nwse')
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.line, = p.plot(self.x,self.y[0:100])
        self.line1, = p.plot(self.x,self.y2[0:100])
        self.line2, = p.plot(self.x,self.y3[0:100])
        self.line3, = p.plot(self.x,self.y4[0:100])
        self.lines = []
        self.ys = []
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(p.bbox)
        self.timer = self.canvas.new_timer(interval=1)
        self.timer.add_callback(self.update,self.lines)
        self.timer.start()

    def check1(self):
        print(self.Int1.get())
        if self.Int1.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line,self.y)
        if self.Int1.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line,self.y)
    def check2(self):
        if self.Int2.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line1,self.y2)
        if self.Int2.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line1,self.y2)
    def check3(self):
        if self.Int3.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line2,self.y3)
        if self.Int3.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line2,self.y3)
    def check4(self):
        if self.Int4.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line3,self.y4)
        if self.Int4.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line3,self.y4)
    def stoptime(self):
        print(self.Int5.get())
        if self.Int5.get() == 1:
            self.timer.stop()
            print("stop!!")

    def remove_line(self,line,y):
        if line in self.lines:
            self.lines.remove(line)
            self.ys.remove(y)
            print("remove!")
        else:
            pass

    def insert_line(self,line,y):
        if line in self.lines:
            pass
        else:
            self.lines.append(line)
            self.ys.append(y)
            print('Sucess')

    def update(self,line):
        if max(self.x) < len(self.dic['x'])-5:
            self.x[:] += 5
            temp = []
            for y in self.ys:
                temp_sub = []
                for index in self.x[:]:
                    temp_sub.append(y[index])
                temp.append(temp_sub)
            for i in range(0,len(temp)):
                self.lines[i].set_ydata(temp[i])
            self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
            for i in range(0,len(temp)):
                self.figure.draw_artist(self.lines[i])
            self.canvas.blit(self.figure.bbox)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
    def __del__(self):
        self.timer.stop()

system = tk.Tk()
system.title('System')
container = tk.Frame(system)
container.pack(side='top',expand=True)
text = tk.Entry(container,width=10)
text.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nwse')
button = ttk.Button(container,text='Analyze!',command=lambda:reader(text,container)).grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nwse')
button2 = ttk.Button(container,text='Exit',command=lambda:system.destroy()).grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='nwse')

system.mainloop()
```

Comment: I might be able to help you, but don't have all those third-party modules installed. Please [edit] your question and provide a **minimal** example that will reproduce the problem. And even if I did, what steps would I need to follow to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thank you for answering ! I have already edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question is still hardly the minimal amount needed to recreate the problem—and for that reason the following is untested and so may have some [minor] mistakes, but that wouldn't change the point being made.

Anyway, the problem is the way you're setting up the `command` option of the `Checkbutton`s.
Here's what you have (rewritten to be more readable and show what's the same and what's different between them):

```
        c1 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_z',
                variable=self.Int1, command=self.check1)
        c2 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='standard_axis',
                variable=self.Int2, command=self.check2)
        c3 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_x',
                variable=self.Int3, command=self.check3)
        c4 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_y',
                variable=self.Int4, command=self.check4)
```

The `command` functions you have which are associated with these are:

```
    def check1(self):
        print(self.Int1.get())
        if self.Int1.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line, self.y)
        if self.Int1.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line, self.y)
    def check2(self):
        if self.Int2.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line1, self.y2)
        if self.Int2.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line1, self.y2)
    def check3(self):
        if self.Int3.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line2, self.y3)
        if self.Int3.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line2, self.y3)
    def check4(self):
        if self.Int4.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(self.line3, self.y4)
        if self.Int4.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(self.line3, self.y4)
```

That's lots of very repetitive code and isn't necessary.
What you need instead is to define a **single** generic `checker()` function that accepts parameters that tell it what data to use, like this:

```
    def checker(self, var, line, y):
        print(var.get())
        if var.get() == 1:
            self.insert_line(line, y)
        if var.get() == 0:
            self.remove_line(line, y)
```

With it you would then be able create the `Checkbutton`s like this:

```
        c1 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_z',
                variable=self.Int1,
                command=lamdba: self.checker(self.Int1, self.line, self.y))
        c2 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='standard_axis',
                variable=self.Int2,
                command=lamdba: self.checker(self.Int2, self.line1, self.y2))
        c3 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_x',
                variable=self.Int3,
                command=lamdba: self.checker(self.Int3, self.line2, self.y3))
        c4 = ttk.Checkbutton(container, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text='axis_y',
                variable=self.Int4,
                command=lamdba: self.checker(self.Int4, self.line3, self.y4))
```

Note how the data is being passed to `checker()` as arguments in each `lambda`. Besides being less code, I think this will fix the problem about always getting the same value from the button.

Comment: Thank you you are right! I clean up my code and I find my errors. Sorry to bother!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the definitions of `c1` and `c5`:

```
    c1 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_z',variable=self.Int1,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
    c5 = ttk.Checkbutton(container,text='axis_z',variable=self.Int5,onvalue=1, offvalue=0,command=self.check1)
```

`c1` toggles a variable named `self.Int1` and calls the method `self.check1`.

`c5` toggles a variable named `self.Int5` and calls the method `self.check1`.

`self.check1` displays the value of `self.Int1`, but `c5` toggles `self.Int5`.  If you've commented out `c1`, nothing will change `self.Int1` and it will remain at zero.

Perhaps you meant to write a method `check5` and put `command=self.check5` for `c5`?

Comment: No I want to prove that same codes function differently. It is weird. Same thing happens when I try to add a button into my codes. It has a constant output

Comment: @LeeDennis I don't understand your comment.  You may have wired up both `c1` and `c5` to the same _code_, but you haven't wired them up to the same _data_, hence the two checkboxes behave differently.  Or perhaps you don't realise that the checkboxes themselves are responsible for changing `self.Int1` and `self.Int5`, rather than any of your code?

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. But I found it is something to do with my self.Int1 and self.Int5. Thank you so much. Silly me! Sorry to bother.